# How to fire event on a button selected using its reference

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am defining a button like this :

```
{
    xtype : 'button',
    reference : 'button1'
}
```

I want to get to be able to select it using this syntax :

```
this.lookupreference("button1");
```

and then fire a click event on it.
Is this syntax correct : `this.lookupreference("button1").fireEvent("click");` ?
If no, then how to do it using the lookupreference ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the method is lookupReference not lookupreference.

[Here is a fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3akt)

Some important things to remember:

The reference cache is based on a controller.  So you have to have a controller in the components hierarchy.

When I did this fiddle i noticed two things, first the button1.fireEvent('click') did not execute the handler method.  The button had to have a 'click' event listener.  Second, the fireEvent did not pass the button by default.  That is the button would be the first argument of the event when the buttons is clicked.  So I passed the button in the fireEvent call.

Comment: Thanks for the great help !